# Multiple Sections in xml properties file

Tags: java, xml, properties-file

in the post located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580005/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-do-settings-files-in-java)

Andrew Finnell's reply was by far the most helpful to a point. I do however need to know how to expand that into allowing other sections other than just

```
<properties>
</properties>
```

If the answer is already on that page please let me know, if not can someone help me out.

Basically I want to have

```
<properties>
</properties>
<blah1>
</blah1>
<blah2>
</blah2>
```

etc... as my sections. All the normal xml libs and such I have found are far to bulky and confusing so I am hoping to be able to use the afore referenced method with much more ease. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An xml file needs excatly *one* root element. Otherwise it is not valid and can't be processed by xml parsers.

A valid xml with *sections* could look like this:

```
<properties>  <!-- root element -->
  <section1>  <!-- section 1 as a child of root -->
  </section1>
  <section2>  <!-- section 2 as a child of root -->
  </section2>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put sections into an XML properties file, it is no longer an XML properties file, and you can't expect to use `java.utils.Properties` to process it.

If your requirement is for properties (name/value pairs) within named sections, then you could use INI file syntax.  There's a Java library for handling this.

If you want something more general, then take a look at JSON.  There are a numer of Java libraries that handle JSON.  (I like Jackson because it allows you to map regular Java beans to JSON.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks for quick responses. I have restructured things a bit and here is my xml. Is this 100% compliant or are minor changes needed?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<settings name="connection">
    <server>test.com</server>
    <name>blah</name>
    <password>blah</password>
    <owner>blah</owner>
    <staff>blah,blH,BLAH,BLah</staff>
    <timercount>5</timercount>
</settings>

<settings name="prvtmsg">
    <hello>Hello %person. How are you today?</hello>
    <commands>I have the following commands: About, Help, and Join</commands>
</setting>

<settings name="timers">
    <timer1>interval,action,delay</timer1>
    <timer2>interval,action,delay</timer2>
    <timer3>interval,action,delay</timer3>
    <timer4>interval,action,delay</timer4>
    <timer5>interval,action,delay</timer5>
</settings>
</configuration>
```